# Is there a generalization of eigen vector for higher-order tensor?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tensors

Like calculating eigen vectors (1st Order tensor) of a matrix (2nd order tensor), is it possible to calculate n-the order eigen tensor of a n+1-st order tensor?

Comment: Your orders are off. After contacting, the order of the resulting tensor should be the same as the smaller order tensor was originally. So you really ought to have a $2n$ tensor and an $n$ tensor.